# События в C#: пример

Tags: c#, события

Изучаю C# по книге - *Шилдт Г. - C# 4.0 полное руководство*, дошел до событий, но не могу их толком понять, приведенный в книге пример просто показывает как вызывать событие, но я не могу понять как он срабатывает, для полного понимания мне нужна программа, в которой событием будет когда определенная переменная станет равна определенному значению, вот более подробно:

дана переменная X, она равна 10, далее запускается цикл, который за каждый шаг увеличивает X на 1, цикл повторяется 10 раз (т.е. в конечном счете X будет равно 20), при X равным 15 должно срабатывать событие, уведомление выводится что то типа "внимание, X = 15!", программа консольная, так же просьба как можно меньше не нужного кода совать, что бы было проще понять как это работает.

Просьба, меня интересует код программы, а НЕ ссылки на какие то статьи, где по большому счету, в более сжатом или развернутом виде, написано тоже само что и в моей книге, то, что я не могу понять.

Comment: Не учто в книжке нет примера кода?

Answer (score 9):

Пожалуйста:

```
public class MyEventArgs
{
    public MyEventArgs(int arg) { Counter = arg; }

    public int Counter { get; private set; } 
}

class Foo {

    private int _counter;

    public int Counter 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _counter;
        }
        set 
        {

            // сначала изменение _counter - это важно. 
            // даже в случае, если в обработчике события возникнет исключение,    
            // _counter все равно будет изменен    
            _counter = value;

            if(value == 15)
                if(OnFifteen != null)
                    OnFifteen(this, new MyEventArgs(value));

        }
    }

    public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs e);

    public event MyEventHandler OnFifteen;

}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo { Counter = 10 };
        foo.OnFifteen += (object o, MyEventArgs arg) =>
             Console.WriteLine("Event fired! Value is {0}", 
                               arg.Counter);

        for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)            
            Console.WriteLine("foo.Counter = {0}", ++foo.Counter);

        Console.RedaLine();
    }
}
```

З.Ы. В следующий раз все же постарайтесь обойтись без понтов типа:

> программа консольная, так же просьба как можно меньше не нужного кода совать
>
> меня интересует код программы, а НЕ ссылки на какие то статьи, где по большому счету, в более сжатом или развернутом виде, написано тоже само что и в моей книге, то, что я не могу понять

Здесь все же помогают исключительно из благих побуждений, и ставить условия тут кому бы то ни было неуместно

Comment: Большое спасибо за пример! к сожалению это понты, я интересовался подобным примером на одном форуме, ни чего кроме ссылок на статьи в которых написано тоже самое, что и в книге мне не дали, новые ссылки мне не нужна потому что от них толку не будет, программа внесла полное понимание.

Comment: а вообще по Шилдту учиться не рекомендуют. Всякое нехорошее про него пишут Правда сам учился по Троелсену, так что про Шилдта ничего плохого или хорошего не скажу. Но если дружите с английским, то погуглите по слову "Bullshildt"

Answer (score 2):

Эх, не успел. Может тоже пригодится, он чуть меньше :)

```
delegate void MyEventHandler();
class MyEvent
{
    public event MyEventHandler SomeEvent;
    void OnSomeEvent()
    {
        if (SomeEvent != null) SomeEvent();
    }
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        int X;
        for (X = 10; X <= 20; X++)
            if (X == 15) OnSomeEvent();
    }

}
class Program
{
    static void Handler()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("X==15");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyEvent me = new MyEvent();
        me.SomeEvent += Handler;
        me.MyMethod();
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Наверное надо `if (X == 15) OnSomeEvent();` ?

Comment: мне кажется, это не очень наглядная иллюстрация работы событий. Вообще событие должно инициироваться в ответ на какие-то внешние действия, а в вашем примере получается, что событие может сработать **только** при вызове метода MyMethod, а это уже просто вызов одного метода внутри другого.

Comment: Чад, спасибо, исправил.

DreamChild, может быть. Просто я тоже учусь по Шилдту и хотел написать пример максимально похожий на книжный, чтобы автору было проще понять.